# Install Cordova plugin without package.json file on it

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to install a Cordova Plugin with Cordova CLI 7.

This plugin does not have a package.json file on it, so it throws an error when adding it to my project.

I've tried converting the config.xml file using plugman. And it works fine for Android but it doesn't for iOS. I feel like I'm missing some configuration from the config.xml in my package.json file.

Is there a way to safely convert the config.xml in a package.json file? or a way to install it using the config.xml file?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, since Cordova 7, the installation of platforms and plugins are by default performed using [cordova-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-fetch) which in turn uses npm install to add/remove modules. Therefore a package.json is required by default. But you should be able to add plugins lacking a package.json file by using the **nofetch** parameter, which forces Cordova to use the old method instead, please note that this parameter has been removed in cordova 8.0.0:

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --nofetch`

Comment: I'm using cordova 8.0.0 and this doesn't seem to work with many plugins. Among them: cordova-plugin-fastrde-checkgps, com.phonegap.plugins.nativesettingsopener, ...

Comment: Cordova 8.0.0 has dropped the option `--no-fetch`: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13055

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer to clarify that the nofetch option has been removed in Cordova 8.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

For me when adding a custom plugin like so

```
cordova plugin add .\custom-plugins\my-plugin --nofetch
```

This does not work on MAC for me for some reason.

I resort to building it all for Android then copy over all the files, except node_modules and platforms, then do a 'cordova build ios' it seems to build fine with the custom plugins included. Not the best way i know, but once the plugin is added i can move on and continue. If you get it to work please share.

Comment: What error message do you get on the Mac when running the plugin add above? Does it work for remote plugins?

Comment: Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/my.package and this is the same error as if i didn't    use --nofetch

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your specific case, but the problem may be related to first trying to add the plugin without the nofetch parameter. This most probably leaves traces in one or more of: npm cache, config.xml, package.json, node_modules/, plugins/ & platforms/. This is detected in subsequent operations related to the same plugin, which leads to fetch/npm being used even when using nofetch.

Try:
1. npm cache clean
2. Remove every reference to the failing cordova plugin from the files and directories mentioned above.

Also: Ensure that you have Node >= 6

Comment: OK i tried this but didn't work, i even created a new project and tried but same result. However i got it working by using the absolute path instead of the relative path ie '/Users/workspace/my-project/custom-plugins/my-plugin --nofetch' thanks

Answer (score 2):

`--nofetch` option is removed in Cordova 8.0.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13055

If you have already installed Cordova 8.x.x then you can downgrade it to version 7.1.0 and then use the `--nofetch` option.

Run the following command to downgrade Cordova to 7.1.0:

```
npm install -g cordova@7.1.0
```

If the above command doesn't work, then try uninstalling cordova at first and then install cordova version 7.1.0:

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova@7.1.0
```

Then, check the Cordova version:

```
cordova --version
```