# Cordova plugin installation and package.json

Tags: cordova-plugins

i am new to cordova.

I created a project using the command `cordova create hello com.example.helloapp Hello`. The Project is created with default folders and files and a `package.json`.

Then, i wanted to add a simple plugin from git *(a hello world plugin for testing)* : `cordova plugin add https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hello.git` .

> I get an error that the file `package.json` dosen't exist in the current directory *(current directory = where i created my project hello that contains that file as said earlier)*, i listed the files with `dir /o`, see screens below :
>   [Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPEVg.jpg) &
>   [Image package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMm7d.jpg)

What am i doing wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like its the plugin which is missing package.json.. not your app

Comment: you can try with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45021702/7393478): it looks like you have cordova version > 7 and that the plugin is not really up to date with new format.

Comment: @Kaddath i tried, didn't work. I think it's the plugin is missing the said file.

Comment: yes, that is actually the problem, since version 7 this new JSON file is needed. If it's just for testing, try this one: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-hello-world`, or any other simple plugin that is recent and compatible to your cordova version, no use to insist with an outdated one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin mentioned is old, IT IS the one who's missing the `.JSON` file.
Found a newer version and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

**

> Create Custom Plugin

**

- plugman create —name CustomPlugin --plugin_id com-SA-plugin --plugin_version 0.0.1

  - cd CustomPlugin
  - plugman platform add - -platform_name ios
  - plugman createpackagejson .

**

> Create Project

**

- cordova create CustomPluginApp com.SA.plugin DemoApp
- cd CustomPluginApp
- cordova plugin add …/CustomPlugin (plugin path)
- cordova platform add ios