# Cordova 8: How do you add plugins that are not in npm registry?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a series of plugins that are not published in the npm registry and for various reasons, they will never be. These exist as GitHub repos.

Given that cordova 8 (actually starting 7.1.0) has removed `nofetch` how do we specify cordova plugins in `config.xml` (or `package.json`) that install these plugins when the user does a `cordova prepare` ?

Example:
This is in package.json (as well as config.xml)

```
 <plugin name="org.devgeeks.Canvas2ImagePlugin" spec="https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin.git">
```

When you do `cordova prepare`

```
Discovered plugin "org.devgeeks.Canvas2ImagePlugin" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Failed to restore plugin "org.devgeeks.Canvas2ImagePlugin" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Failed to get absolute path to installed module
```

However manually doing the same thing works just fine:

```
cordova plugin add  https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin.git
Installing "org.devgeeks.Canvas2ImagePlugin" for android
Installing "org.devgeeks.Canvas2ImagePlugin" for ios
Adding org.devgeeks.Canvas2ImagePlugin to package.json
Saved plugin info for "org.devgeeks.Canvas2ImagePlugin" to config.xml
```

This particular plugin does not have an npm registry. The same holds true for any other plugin that doesn't have an npm registry.

Comment: It looks like cordova dropped the ball here and broke cordova prepare if you have plugins without an npm registry.  I think you're stuck manually adding those ones for now

Answer (score 7):

(Not marking this as an answer, because I did the opposite of what I wanted to do)

I gave up trying to do this. It was much simpler  to publish my changes to the npm registry with a different ID. I personally think this is a terrible mechanism - I consider the npm registry as a 'good list of plugins' and really shouldn't be littered with modifications that don't add a global value, but I found no option.

So I:

- Changed the ids of all my changed plugins to `originalplugin-myid-fork`
- Published them to npm registry
- Changed my `package.json` and `config.xml` to just refer to these ids as they are now on npm registry (I like them both to be in sync)

**Backstory** (for context and what I tried):

My criteria was to make it easy for my users to install my software simply by doing `npm install && bower install && cordova prepare`

- The problem is `npm install` would create the plugin shims inside `node_modules` which had the same ids as the original plugins.
- Even though my `config.xml` and `package.json` had a `spec="my fork url"`, for whatever reason, `cordova prepare` would go looking for that id in the npm registry and start complaining.
- In fact, after doing `npm install` a manual install of `cordova plugin add https://mygit.git` would fail with the same error. The only way to make this manual command work again was to remove that plugin's definition from `node_modules`.
- I also saw `--no-registry` option - could never get it working - kept complaining about missing local paths.
- Around this time, I said *meh* and decided it was not worth it and lets go dirty the registry with my forks

Comment: This sucks man, I'm having the same issue. Did you ever find a better way?

Comment: Nope - I gave up looking for the "right" way after I forked and published everything.

Comment: Solved in the same way. Published my forked plugin on the npm registry to avoid id clashes.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. There used to be an option --nofetch to install plugins without a package.json/npm. This option was dropped in cordova@8.0.0 without replacement it seems.

A solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49535961/3091226) is to downgrade to cordova@7.1.0

Comment: Yes, I actually state that in my original question